# How to use a test action in a play framework 2.4 route file?

Tags: testing, playframework, controller, routes, playframework-2.0

I have defined some test action in a controller in test folder but i can not use them in route file (test.routes) and i have got error form Play's route compiler.

Comment: Some code and the aforementioned error would be helpful.

Comment: @sebster what is your question? i think it is clear.

Comment: You can't access test code from your production code and since `routes` is contained in your production code... Why do you need to use a test controllers? What are you trying to do?